# Awk how to find a match of variable with paranthesis?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I have a file `some_file.txt` , in which I want to find a match line by `name` inside square brackets (it must bee exact match as some words may be repeated - like `foo` in example below).
The document contents looks like this:

```
[foo](url)
[foo Foo](url)
[bar (Bar)](url)
[fizz buzz](url)
```

I came up with the following, but it breaks when you specify `name` with paranthesis.

```bash
file="some_file.txt"

name="foo" # Good
name="foo Foo" # Good
name="bar (Bar)" # No match :(
name="fizz buzz" # Good

matched_line=$(awk -v n="${name}]" '$0 ~ n {print NR}' "${file}")
```

I tried to escape paranthesis like so `name="bar \(Bar\)"`, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a non-regex search using `index` function:

```bash
awk -v n='bar (Bar)' 'index($0, n) {print NR}' file
3

# be more precise and search with surrounding [ .. ]
awk -v n='bar (Bar)' 'index($0, "[" n "]") {print NR}' file
3
```

`index` function preforms plain text search in `awk` hence it **doesn't require any escaping** of special characters.

Using all search terms:

```bash
for name in 'foo' 'foo Foo' 'bar (Bar)' 'fizz buzz'; do
   awk -v n="$name" 'index($0, "[" n "]") {print NR, n}' file
done

1 foo
2 foo Foo
3 bar (Bar)
4 fizz buzz
```

Comment: If you really want to overkill it, you could do `index($0,"[" n "]") == 1`

Comment: @kvantour IMHO that'd be required, not overkill, since URLs can contain square and round brackets so there's a chance of a false match otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to escape paranthesis like so `name="bar \(Bar\)"`, but it
> doesn't help.

I run simple test using GNU `AWK` 4.2.1

```
awk -v n="\(something\)" 'BEGIN{print n}'
```

and got

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'
(something)
```

This is reason, but how to get desired result? Stuff more escape characters, after test I found `\\\` is required, that is

```
awk -v n="\\\(something\\\)" 'BEGIN{print n}'
```

gives

```
\(something\)
```

Final test: check if it could be used for string matching, let `file.txt` content be

```
foo bar
foo (bar)
(foo) bar
(foo) (bar)
```

then

```
awk -v n="foo \\\(bar\\\)" '$0 ~ n' file.txt
```

gives output

```
foo (bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an ***absolutely*** amazing textbook case of inconsistent treatment among `awks`  -

- half of them attempted to process it as a `regex` for no reason even though it was never requested to perform the role of a `regex string constant` anywhere within the code itself. seems only `mawk`s consistently treat them literally (the correct approach) :

> ```
>   mawk  -v __='\(something\)' 'BEGIN { print __,"mawk-1" } '; 
>   mawk2 -v __='\(something\)' 'BEGIN { print __,"mawk-2" } ';
> ```

> ```
>   nawk  -v __='\(something\)' 'BEGIN { print __,"nawk" }';
> ```

> ```
>   gawk  -v __='\(something\)' 'BEGIN { print __, "gawk-one-slash" } ';  
>   gawk -v __='\\(something\\)' 'BEGIN { print __,"gawk-dbl-slash" } ';
>   gawk 'END { print __,   "gawk-END-no-esc " }'  __='(something)' <<<"";  
>   gawk -v __='\\(something\\)' -ce 'BEGIN { print __ , "gawk-ce-dbl-slsh" } '
> ```

|

```
     1  \(something\) mawk-1
     2  \(something\) mawk-2
     3  (something) nawk
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
gawk: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'
     4  (something) gawk-one-slash
     5  \(something\) gawk-dbl-slash
     6  (something) gawk-END-no-esc 
     7  \(something\) gawk-ce-dbl-slsh
```

Comment: If you place a backslash in a string constant before something that is not a special character (eg \n, \r,\a,...), POSIX awk purposely leaves what happens as undefined. GNU awk chooses to remove the backslash and warn you about it, while mawk leaves it in. Two different approaches to handle undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kvantour : It's just baffling to me POSIX thinks `<<<'\(123\)' gawk '{ print __=$_ }'` vs. `gawk -v __='\(123\)' 'BEGIN { print __ }'` deserves different treatment

Comment: I think you hit an interesting note of subtleties. The main difference I see is that the former case uses file input while the later is a string constant. But I would need to have a closer look what is going on here.