# matching a variable containing parentheses in awk

Tags: awk

Is it possible to use a variable containing parentheses as a string to be matched against?

`echo 'foo(bar)' | awk -v var='foo(bar)' '$0~var{print "hahaha"}'`

`echo 'foobar' | awk -v var='foobar' '$0~var{print "hahaha"}'`

only the second example produces an output

i also tried escaping the parentheses but all i got was the following

```
echo 'foo(bar)' | awk -v var='foo\(bar\)' '$0~var{print "hahaha"}'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\(' treated as plain `('
awk: warning: escape sequence `\)' treated as plain `)'
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Kindly check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73148903/awk-how-to-find-a-match-of-variable-with-paranthesis if this is helpful to you once, thank you.

Comment: Try escaping the opening parenthesis `awk -v var="foo\\\(bar)" '$0~var{print "hahaha"}'`